# Remote execute Power Shell scripts to collect data

Tags: powershell

I am looking to collect data snapshot on a random interval from various machines in our network that we don't own, but may get access to install an agent to collect these data.

These machines are either in a domain or work-group and kind of data i get are based on the role they play and information they have. The machines are "Windows Server 2003" and above and I do not want to install anything on those machines before i get started, so thought I can use the PowerShell scripts that I can remote invoke form my server and pass the script it has to run to return the data.

[image]

I was wondering if this is possible to do that with the PowerShell scripts and as this is supposed to run in a secure environment, is there any major security implications with this approach. i.e. do I need to do anything on the client machines that can make them vulnerable to security threats.

BTW these machines are not exposed to internet and are behind a firewall.

I would appreciate if you point me to any other alternatives that can be useful for my analysis.

Regards
Kiran

Comment: PowerShell seems reasonable for this task and it can be done securely. Many of your questions are answered in "Secrets of PowerShell Remoting" (free eBook) http://powershell.org/wp/ebooks/
Windows Server 2003 might be a bit of a restriction - but maybe you can update PowerShell on these machines?

Comment: @Swonkie I don't think the book is available anymore for download. Basically looks like the domain name has expired, is there any other location where I can get good information on this?

Comment: There's a link on that page to their OneDrive site where you can download it:
https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=7f868aa697b937fe&id=7F868AA697B937FE%21107

Comment: @Swonkie: Thanks, it works. I think the site was blocked in office so was not able to access it.